# Semaphore does not wait before executing block of code after it

Tags: ios, swift, semaphore

I'm fairly new at using semaphores so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

When I try to do this:

```
var group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)){

    var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        // do some stuff once
        println("WE ARE IN HERE")   
        firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
        lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!
    })
}
dispatch_semaphore_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
dispatch_semaphore_signal(group)
println("WE MADE IT OUT OF THERE")
```

The output is always:

```
"WE MADE IT OUF OF THERE"
"WE ARE IN HERE"
```

Why doesn't it wait for my semaphore to finish before executing the rest of the code?

EDIT:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
        // do some task
        var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
        myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            // do some stuff once
            println("WE ARE IN HERE")
            firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
            lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!
        })
});

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> () in
    // do some task
    var standbyData = [
        "firstName":firstName,
        "lastName":lastName,
        "duration":self.helpDurationLabel.text!,
        "radius":self.helpRadiusLabel.text!,
        "categories": categories,
        "time_stamp":self.date.timeIntervalSince1970
    ]
    println("WE ARE OUT HERE")
    var standbyUserRef = self.standbyRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyData)
});
```

Shouldn't this work since I'm putting 2 synchronous threads in the same queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up a couple concepts there—dispatch groups and semaphores are used for different purposes. You'll need to (1) create a semaphore, (2) in your block, signal the semaphore, and (3) wait for the semaphore outside the block:

**Note:** This will block whatever thread it's running on while waiting, so if it's on the main thread it will suspend user interactions—not a good idea. You'd do best to read Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) to understand the rest of the concepts.

```
var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)){
    var myRef = self.userRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userRef.authData.uid)
    myRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        // do some stuff once
        println("WE ARE IN HERE")   
        firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"] as String!
        lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"] as String!
    })
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
}
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
println("WE MADE IT OUT OF THERE")
```